# Add a quick Step for an item

Tags: sharepoint-designer, custom-actions

In Sharepoint 2013, I have created a quick step for a list, and it shows up just fine, but what I really want is a quickstep when the user is editing one item.  I have tried creating a "Custom Action" in Sharepoint designer and attaching it to the Edit Form Ribbon and expected it to show up in the picture below, but it doesn't   What am I missing?
[image: Edit List Item]

Answer (score 0):

The quick step buttons are visible when you select an item, but not in the edit form.

**2013**
[image]

**SP Online**
[image]